# Can I compete with 20 domain authority in a high-paid niche?

Tags: seo, local-seo, marketing, technical-seo, sem

I have found a niche in which demand is relatively high for a freelancer, but all top websites have 10-20 domain authority, and I think I can achieve more than that. Considering this niche is related to language services with highly-paid customers, can I compete with them? i.e. I wonder why in this niche top websites' DA is low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You *Can* Compete, but Don't Look at Domain Authority to Gauge Your Competition

Domain Authority is (IMO *was*) a metric developed by Moz in 1999. The original algorithm was primarily based on PageRank. In 2019, the company launched Domain Authority 2.0 - which now adds some degree of machine learning into the formula.

> As of the Domain Authority 2.0 update in early 2019, the calculation of a domain's DA score comes from a machine learning algorithm’s predictions about how often Google is using that domain in its search results. If domain A is more likely to appear in a Google SERP than domain B is, then we would expect domain A's DA to be higher than domain B's DA.

I still don't trust it, in fact I take *all* software proprietary metrics with a grain of salt. How can I *trust* something I don't understand? I go by instincts and observation. John Mueller has reaffirmed many times that Google does not have a domain authority metric or signal in use at Google.

BNazaruk is spot on - don't pay attention to it. Many of the most talented SEOs I know don't even use tools.

### Optimize On-Page & Technical, Load Fast, Have a Good UX, and Create *Better* Content

When I think about how to rank on a SERP, rather than looking at what all of the results on the first page *are* doing (in their content), I look at what they're *not* doing that is highly relevant to the query.

So within this niche of yours, look for queries where you can add unique value to the overall SERP - how can you make it more diverse?

### Proof that Good Content *is* Good Enough

Here is a screenshot of my site with a DA 3 and 1 backlink ranking 2nd for the term "keyword concatenation tool".

[image: proof that you can rank good content regardless of domain authority]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was really helpful. However, unfortunately good content isn't enough for competing. I can get good quality backlinks, I can write better and more in depth content, but at the end of the day, Google tend to not trust newer websites over older ones. I think this is unfair

Comment: @PooryaZeynalzadeh of course domain age plays a factor that's just how the internet works. I encourage you to not actively _go far out of your way_  to build links. Let your content do that for you - if it has the merits you'll rank just fine. I've updated my answer with a screenshot that you should find interesting.

Comment: My domain was maybe 3 months old at the time that screenshot was taken.

Answer (score 4):

DA is not a strong indicator of competitiveness. It's is not a reflection of actual authority Google assigns.

Practice shows, best SEO results are achieved when people pay zero attention to DA, instead using less processed, but more raw metrics.

But to answer your question: if DA is everything there is to those sites, then sure, you can compete using only DA :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course DA isn't everything, but I though everything was counted in calculating DA.

Comment: No, not even close to everything, not even a quarter of everything. Moreover, in life, there's almost never a metric where everything that matters would be counted.